# VNC and copy/paste

Tags: windows, vnc

Is there a way to copy and paste between two Windows machines (one a physical machine, the other a VM on a Linux KVM), when connecting via VNC (TightVNC in this case).

If not, what is the best way to transfer files to the virtualised server from my physical machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of TightVNC support file transfers:

[image]

You could also make a windows share on the destination machine and copy files to the share from the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention which is your VM

in VirtualBox there is feature "shared folders" for this purpose